# Async access of Database

Tags: asynchronous

I have problem accessing database async.

My scenario is:
My application is based in ASP.NET, Web API & SignalR. 
Using SignalR, I have send message to multiple to call update the data. That Javascript method call Web API method using AJAX to fetch data from database.

As the database connection is single; and at usthe same time request is trying to fetch data. So, all request serve instantly, but once the data fetch for one request and reader put all data in object and leave the method. It will create for all the other method call as the connection is closed.

Is any one has solution for this, how can I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a different instance of connection for each of the data reader?